# How do I type Home/End/PageUp/PageDown on a MacBook Pro?

Tags: keyboard, macbook

What combination of keys (fn, control, option, command, arrow keys) is the equivalent of the Home key on a MacBook Pro?

What about End/PageUp/PageDown?

Comment: I use a free program called Karabiner https://pqrs.org/osx/karabiner/ which lets me reprogram keys, and then I setup RIGHT_COMMAND as HOME and RIGHT_OPTION as END (you can assign specific changes to only work in specific apps if you want).And FYI I also change EJECT button to be BACKSPACE and FUNCTION+EJECT to Eject.

Comment: As of Big Sur, macOS 11, most of the answers work at least partially. As noted in some of the answers, this seems to be application dependent (eg, what works in Safari, say, may not work in Terminal; what works in Terminal may not work in Safari; what works in Safari, likely works in Apple products and Mac-designed apps, but not guaranteed).

Answer (score 200, accepted):

- **Home** is <kbd>Fn</kbd> <kbd>←</kbd>
- **End** is <kbd>Fn</kbd> <kbd>→</kbd>
- **Page Up** is <kbd>Fn</kbd> <kbd>↑</kbd>
- **Page Down** is <kbd>Fn</kbd> <kbd>↓</kbd>
- **Forward Delete** is <kbd>Fn</kbd> <kbd>delete</kbd>
- **Insert** is <kbd>Fn</kbd> <kbd>return</kbd><sup>*2</sup>

They used to label these on older MacBooks/PowerBooks.

Note 1: Not every application respects this, or behaves as expected.

Terminal is a notable example; for <kbd>Fn</kbd> <kbd>arrow</kbd> to work as expected when coming from a Linux background, the [settings must be changed](http://theandystratton.com/2009/fixing-home-end-page-up-and-page-down-in-leopards-terminal).

Note 2: OS X by default has no <kbd>Insert</kbd> functionality, however it is respected in some situations being Virtual Machines, Bootcamp, other Remote Desktops. Notably it also works in Google Chrome extensions that expect the <kbd>Insert</kbd> key for some other functionality (other than overtyping, which does not exist in OS X). Be careful though, in text boxes, dialog boxes and the like, it will always act as an <kbd>enter</kbd> key.

Comment: Just want to add that Ctrl+Home and Ctrl+End in Windows are the same as Fn + ⌘ + ← and Fn + ⌘ + → respectively.  These combinations allow you to jump to the beginning and end of the document.

Comment: I've known about page up/down for a while, but needed Home and End tonight... thanks. I hope you don't mind, but I submitted an edit for [Insert] and [>|] (forward delete) to the repertoire only to complete the number pad out :)

Comment: this is not working in default osx terminal

Answer (score 37):

In text editors such as TextEdit or Pages:

- Beginning of Wrapped Line (reposition cursor) is <kbd>⌘</kbd><kbd>←</kbd>
- End of Wrapped Line (reposition cursor) is <kbd>⌘</kbd><kbd>→</kbd>
- Beginning of Line (reposition cursor) is <kbd>⌃</kbd><kbd>A</kbd>
- End of Line (reposition cursor) is <kbd>⌃</kbd><kbd>E</kbd>
- Page Up (reposition cursor) is <kbd>Fn</kbd><kbd>⌥</kbd><kbd>↑</kbd>
- Page Down (reposition cursor) is <kbd>Fn</kbd><kbd>⌥</kbd><kbd>↓</kbd> or <kbd>⌃</kbd><kbd>V</kbd>

Answer (score 8):

I found that I need to use the <kbd>Command</kbd> + whatever arrow/directional key you need

Answer (score 8):

I have a 2011 Macbook Air. <kbd>Fn</kbd> with the arrow-keys did not work for me.

It seems that <kbd>Command</kbd> + <kbd>Right Arrow</kbd> is the equivalent of <kbd>End</kbd>.

Comment: Same here with an 2013 Air.  Annoying since I'm used to Fn+L/R on my MacBook Pro and now have to break the habit.

Comment: I concur. At my new job they've just given me a new 2014 MacBook Pro with OSX Mavericks and I found that the ⌘ + ← works for "Home", as in "jump to the beginning of a line".

Comment: Except in Chrome on a MBP, I thought I would just try this and see what happens.... damn thing took me back a page lol

Answer (score 2):

In XCode 4.4 (MacOS X 10.6) for the MacBook pro, the <kbd>Fn</kbd>-direction keys don't work to navigate to beginning / end / top / bottom of lines.

Only the <kbd>Command</kbd> + directional key buttons work.

Answer (score 1):

I have a MacBookPro and the fn and left arrow takes me to beginning of text and fn and right arrow takes me to ed of text. cmd also performs the same functions.  Only fn and up or down arrows will page up or down.

Answer (score 0):

Some programs also respect:

- go to the beginning of a document <kbd>Fn</kbd><kbd>⌘</kbd><kbd>←</kbd>
- go to the end of a document <kbd>Fn</kbd><kbd>⌘</kbd><kbd>→</kbd>

(this works for me in editors and IDEs written in Java)

Answer (score 0):

I love to use secureshell when ssh-ing different servers. For me the way to pageup pagedown is:

- Page Up: <kbd>Fn</kbd><kbd>⌥</kbd><kbd>↑</kbd>
- Page Down: <kbd>Fn</kbd><kbd>⌥</kbd><kbd>↓</kbd>

Answer (score -2):

⌘ + ↓ gets to the end of the document

⌘ + ↑ gets to the beginning of the document

Comment: This was previously stated.