# Macbook Pro keyboard with BootCamp - missing the Home/End/PageUp/PageDown keys

Tags: windows, keyboard, keyboard-shortcuts, macbook, boot-camp

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How do I type Home on a MacBook Pro?](https://superuser.com/questions/132719/how-do-i-type-home-on-a-macbook-pro)

Last year I converted from Windows to a MacBook Pro and went through the process of learning the ways of the Mac keyboard.  In particular, I learned that Ctrl-left and Ctrl-right were the Mac way of doing Home and End.

I'm now doing a project on Windows 7 on Bootcamp, and finding that I'm missing the Windows Home and End keys in a completely different way -- they don't exist, but the Mac combos don't work either.

Any suggestions for getting this functionality somehow?  Code editing is a real drag without these keys.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You want Fn + arrow keys.