# where is HOME and END key for MacBook Pro?

Tags: mac, keyboard, macbook

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How do I type Home on a MacBook Pro?](https://superuser.com/questions/132719/how-do-i-type-home-on-a-macbook-pro)

I am using a MacBook Pro running Mac OS X 10.5. I am new to this development environment, and previously worked on Windows.

I am wondering what is the HOME key (goes to the begin position of a line in text file) and END key (goes to the end position of a line in text file) on the Mac? My MacBook Pro seems to not have these two keys on the keyboard.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Seems like a dup of either http://superuser.com/questions/132719/how-do-i-type-home-on-a-macbook-pro or http://superuser.com/questions/135030/macbook-pro-keyboard-with-bootcamp-missing-the-home-end-pageup-pagedown-keys