# page-up and page-down key on Mac?

Tags: mac, keyboard, macbook

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How do I type Home on a MacBook Pro?](https://superuser.com/questions/132719/how-do-i-type-home-on-a-macbook-pro)

I am using a MacBook Pro running Mac OS X 10.5. I am new to this development environment, and previously worked on Windows.

I am wondering what is the page-up and page-down key on the Mac? My MacBook Pro seems to not have these two keys on the keyboard.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Short answer: <kbd>fn</kbd>+<kbd>up arrow</kbd> for page up, <kbd>fn</kbd>+<kbd>down arrow</kbd> for page down.

---

More than you asked for:

On all browsers I have installed (Safari, Firefox & Chrome), I tend to use <kbd>space</kbd> and <kbd>shift</kbd>+<kbd>space</kbd> more often.

External keyboards (with built-in page up and page down keys) work well, too.